# Change JSON hierarchy by SQL query in Oracle

Tags: sql, json, database, oracle, clob

I have a table with clob that contains JSON. The JSON already exists, I need to change the hierarchy of the first value.

This is the original json:

```
{
  "configurationByAssetType" :
  {
    "default" :
    {
      "sections" :
      [
....
]
}}}
```

I need to put configurationByAssetType under new section - configurationByView:

```
{
"configurationByView"
{
 "default" :{
  "configurationByAssetType" :
  {
    "default" :
    {
      "sections" :
      [
....
]
}}}}}
```

I want to copy all existing data to be under:

```
{
"configurationByView"
{
 "default" :{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just not to concatenate necessary characters to the beginning and end of the clob:

```
with q as
 (select to_clob('{  "configurationByAssetType" :
                {
                  "default" :
                  {
                    "sections" :
                    [
              ....
              ]
              }}}') clob_json
from dual) 
select '{
"configurationByView"
    {
  "default" :{' || clob_json || '}}}'
  from q;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the exactly what I thought also after I wrote the question.